# Correct horoscope of Lord Rama and Ravana

Tags: rama, ravana, horoscopes

Where can I the find correct horoscope of Lord Rama and Ravana?

Comment: horscope, you mean prophecy on their kundali or their kundali (the janmapatrika) according to their birth dates/tithis?.

Comment: @Yogi - I meant janmkundli according to their birth dates.

Comment: this link might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSrL8fNWAmk

Comment: Ravan is 24/11 Shatavisha/kumbh

Answer (score 2):

Getting horoscope of Rama and Ravana wasn't a cake walk. I referred and grabbed some of the horoscope soft copies of these two legends.

Rama's horoscope:

[image]

and Ravana's horoscope:

[image]

One of the interesting things is that the horoscope of Ravana resembles that of a great scientist.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Comment: Which great scientist?

Comment: Ravana's chart is not possible as max difference between Sun and Venus is 47°. Sun in Simha and Venus in Vrishabha not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Rasis occupied by planets and lagna in Sri Rama's chart are:

- Aries - Sun
- Taurus - Mercury
- Gemini - Ketu
- Cancer - Ascendant (Lagna), Moon & Jupiter
- Libra - Saturn
- Sagittarius - Rahu
- Capricorn - Mars
- Pisces - Venus

Based on the above data, the chart of Sri Rama as per North Indian Format is

[image: Sri Rama Rasi Chart]

*Note: The above is only a partial answer, will update with Ravana's chart as well when I get the necessary data.*